# How can I parse a CSV file and display only specific column?

Tags: python, csv

`python sliceCsv.py`

Total no. of rows: **329375**

Field names are:

> **Note** : ***Handle*** is the first column

```
Handle, Command, Title, Body (HTML), Vendor, Type, Tags, Published, Option1 Name, Option1 Value, Option2 Name, Option2 Value, Option3 Name, Option3 Value, Variant SKU, Variant Grams, Variant Inventory Tracker, Variant Inventory Qty, Variant Inventory Policy, Variant Fulfillment Service, Variant Price, Variant Compare At Price, Variant Requires Shipping, Variant Taxable, Variant Barcode, Image Src, Image Position, Image Alt Text, Gift Card, Google Shopping / MPN, Google Shopping / Age Group, Google Shopping / Gender, Google Shopping / Google Product Category, SEO Title, SEO Description, Google Shopping / AdWords Grouping, Google Shopping / AdWords Labels, Google Shopping / Condition, Google Shopping / Custom Product, Google Shopping / Custom Label 0, Google Shopping / Custom Label 1, Google Shopping / Custom Label 2, Google Shopping / Custom Label 3, Google Shopping / Custom Label 4, Variant Image, Variant Weight Unit, Variant Tax Code, Cost per item, Metafield: theme.Applications [string], Metafield: theme.Applications with Dilutions [string], Metafield: theme.Background [string], Metafield: theme.Notes [string], Metafield: theme.Category [string], Metafield: theme.Clonality [string], Metafield: theme.Clone Number [string], Metafield: theme.Concentration [string], Metafield: theme.Conjugation [string], Metafield: theme.Cross Reactive Species [string], Metafield: theme.Predicted Reactivity [string], Metafield: theme.Datasheet URL [string], Metafield: theme.Excitation Emission [string], Metafield: theme.Gene ID [string], Metafield: theme.Gene ID Link [string], Metafield: theme.Host [string], Metafield: theme.images [string], Metafield: theme.Immunogen Sequence [string], Metafield: theme.Isotype [string], Metafield: theme.Lead Time [string], Metafield: theme.Modification [string], Metafield: theme.Modification Site [string], Metafield: theme.Product URL [string], Metafield: theme.publications [string], Metafield: theme.Purification [string], Metafield: theme.Size [string], Metafield: theme.Source [string], Metafield: theme.Specificity [string], Metafield: theme.Storage [string], Metafield: theme.Storage Buffer [string], Metafield: theme.Storage Condition [string], Metafield: theme.Subcellular Locations [string], Metafield: theme.Swiss Prot [string], Metafield: theme.Swiss Prot Link [string], Metafield: theme.Synonyms [string], Metafield: theme.Target Protein [string], Metafield: theme.AllConjugations,
```

and

```
First row are:


  bs-0637R      MERGE P38 MAPK Polyclonal Antibody                 Company            Primary Antibody, P38 MAPK, target-protein_P38 MAPK, RK, p38, CSBP, EXIP, Mxi2, CSBP1, CSBP2, CSPB1, PRKM14, PRKM15, SAPK2A, p38ALPHA, Mitogen-activated protein kinase 14, MAP kinase 14, MAPK 14, Cytokine suppressive anti-inflammatory drug-binding protein, CSAID-binding protein, MAP kinase MXI2, MAX-interacting protein 2, Mitogen-activated protein kinase p38 alpha, MAP kinase p38 alpha, Stress-activated protein kinase 2a, MAPK14, Human, cross-reactive-species_Human, Mouse, cross-reactive-species_Mouse, Rat, cross-reactive-species_Rat, Rabbit, cross-reactive-species_Rabbit, Others, cross-reactive-species_Others, Dog, predicted-reactivity_Dog, Unmodified, modification_Unmodified, Rabbit, host_Rabbit, Polyclonal, clonality_Polyclonal, IgG, isotype_IgG, WB, applications_WB, ELISA, applications_ELISA, FCM, applications_FCM, IHC-P, applications_IHC-P, IHC-F, applications_IHC-F, IF(IHC-P), applications_IF(IHC-P), IF(IHC-F), applications_IF(IHC-F), IF(ICC), applications_IF(ICC), ICC, applications_ICC, Unconjugated, conjugation_Unconjugated       TRUE     Volume      100ul                                               bs-0637R         45    shopify        100   continue     manual        340                  TRUE       TRUE                                                  FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                         lb                       WB, ELISA, FCM, IHC-P, IHC-F, IF(IHC-P), IF(IHC-F), IF(ICC), ICC WB(1:300-5000), ELISA(1:500-1000), FCM(1:20-100), IHC-P(1:200-400), IHC-F(1:100-500),...
```

As you can see, there are a lot of columns. How can I list only specific columns? `Handle`

[image]

## I've tried (sliceCsv.py)

```
# importing csv module
import sys
import csv

# Fix this error : _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
    
# csv file name
filename = "/Users/code/Desktop/shopify.csv"

keepColumns = ['Handle']


# initializing the titles and rows list
fields = []
rows = []


print('\n====================================================================================\n')



# reading csv file
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # extracting field names through first row
    fields = next(csvreader)

    # extracting each data row one by one
    for row in csvreader:


        # print(row)
        # return False # return False # SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
        # break
        rows.append(row)

    # get total number of rows
    print("Total no. of rows: %d"%(csvreader.line_num))


print('\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n')

# printing the field names
print('Field names are: \n\n' + ', '.join(field for field in fields))

print('\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n')


#  printing first 5 rows
print('\nFirst row are:\n\n')
for row in rows[:1

]:
    # parsing each column of a row
    for col in row:
        print("%10s"%col),
    print('\n')
```

---

My ideal check would be sth like this... I'm not sure how to do it in Python or CSV parser.

```
if(row.header == "Handle") {
    rows.append(row)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *display* exactly ? Do you want to write it into another file or print it to stdout or something ?

Comment: print it to stdout would be ideal for now. write it into another file maybe tomorrow. I will attempt that;

Comment: `rows` is a list of lists. Each element in `rows` is a list representing _one row_ of your CSV. Each element of this list is a cell in your CSV. Do you want to read the entire CSV into memory and only display one column, or do you want to read only one column of the CSV?

Comment: If it's the former, change the code where you _display_ your file: Don't display all `for col in row`, only display the one element of `row` that you care about. If it's the latter, change the part where you store `row` into `rows`. Don't append the entire row, just append the one element of `row` you care about.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to save the data in `rows` if you are not planning to write it somewhere else. You can use `DictReader` if you need access to columns by their names.

```py
import csv

with open("example.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row["Handle"])
```

```
  bs-0637R      MERGE P38 MAPK Polyclonal Antibody                 Company            Primary Antibody
  bs-0637R      MERGE P38 MAPK Polyclonal Antibody                 Company            Primary Antibody
...
```

PS: This is pretty basic stuff, I suggest you to go over the fundamentals again to have a stronger grasp.

Comment: I see that you use first elemenet `line[0]`, It will only work for Handle case since it's the first one, and we kind of know it by looking at it.  I would like to check for specific one `Variant SKU`, then, I won't know which index to access. Can I check for the column name and maybe potentially display multiple columns base on `keepColumns = ['Handle', 'Variant SKU','anything']`

Comment: @code8888 updated answer for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar project, I applied the below strategy to get a specific column. I have changed the code a little bit as per your needs. The loop goes over each row and adds the specific column value to the handle_data list. You can access any row in this loop or multiple rows as well.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(f)
handle_data = []
for id, row in df.iterrows():
    handle_data.append(row['Handle'])
```

Comment: so I can only access `row['Handle']` if I use `pandas`

Comment: not the only way, but a proven working strategy.

Comment: I'm looking to use what I have now with just the csv package, but if no one answer more today, I will try pandas. Thanks .

Comment: Sure, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a general tool for slicing up a CSV, and don't want or need to write a program, I recommend downloading one of GoCSV's [prebuilt binaries](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases) and using its [select](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#select) command:

```
gocsv select -c 'Handle' YOUR-FILE.csv
```

You can use any valid column name or column number, `gocsv select -c 1 ...` will get you the same result.

You can direct the output to a file, `... -c 'Handle' YOUR-FILE.csv > just_handle.csv`, or pipe the output to:

- its built-in table viewer to visually inspec, `... YOUR-FILE.csv | gocsv view`
- its **stats** command to get an overview of the kind of data in the column, `... | gocsv stats`

It's fast, and usually has low memory usage.

I've written many custom one-off CSV Python scripts and I'm very grateful I found this tool.